# Upgraded FileHelpers library and now my code is obsolete

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, filehelpers

I use reflection to specify the class name dynamically when I do file imports using FileHelpers like this ...

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
AssemblyName assemblyName = assembly.GetName();
Type t = assembly.GetType(assemblyName.Name + ".FileDefinitions." + className);
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(t);
```

After getting the latest version of the library what I was doing above now considered "obsolete"

The implementation has been changed to generics in this manner

```
FileHelperEngine<myImportDefinitionClass> = new
                                 FileHelperEngine<myImportDefinitionClass>();
```

but I am not sure how to specify the `myImportDefintionClass` dynamically at runtime, using the original reflection code doesn't work.

UPDATE : After trying Paul's code I would now need to be able to do access the methods or whatever within the FileHelpers class such as *(this part doesn't compile)*

```
fileHelperEngine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;

importData = fileHelperEngine.ReadFileAsDT(filepath);
```

But I am not real clear about what is actually going on. Any links to better understand the generics concepts would be appreciated also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breadtruck

I commited the changes with the [Obsolote] attribute yesterday, in fact was to check some examples of the lib for the next release, but are removed now.

You can do an SVN update and recompile it to avoid the warning, sorry for the problems :(

Marcos

Comment: I was still able to use my old code, it was more a matter of just understanding and fixing it, before it didn't work. I presume that I can keep getting the artifacts off teamcity? Great work by the way, helps me do what I need :)

Comment: You don't need to change nothing of your code because is perfect.

I strong recomend you to download the Stable branch instead of the trunk because you can catch a bug, we are using the stable branch at my work without problems.

For example today we finish the build with the version for .net 2.0 and 4.0 to avoid problems, we are also thinking in provide builds for AnyCpu/x86/x64 because of the posible problems that Visual Studio has

Answer (score 2):

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
AssemblyName assemblyName = assembly.GetName();
Type emptyGenericType = typeof(FileHelperEngine<>);
Type genericTypeArgument = assembly.GetType(assemblyName.Name + ".FileDefinitions." + className);
Type completeGenericType = emptyGenericType.MakeGenericType(genericTypeArgument);
var fileHelperEngine = Activator.CreateInstance(completeGenericType);
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to the cast the resulting object directly to the generic type, c# does not implement duck typing.

I suppose you have two options, use an interface or base class and cast to that, fileHelperEngine does not implement any interfaces, nor does it base class have any useful methods, so that isn't useful. You could change the code and implement one if the licence permits.

The other option is to test the type, this is hacky, but ok if the list of possibilities is small, eg:

```
if (fileHelperEngine is FileHelperEngine<string>)
    fileHelperEngine = fileHelperEngine as FileHelperEngine<string>;
```

etc

Comment: So at this point I have put your code in but how would I then access the methods within the FileHelperClass?

Comment: I am confused by the statement "FileHelperEngine does not implement any interfaces, nor does its base class have any useful methods"? From the docs   .....public class FileHelperEngine<T> : EventEngineBase<T>, 
 IFileHelperEngine<T>
where T : class

.... Doesn't the IFileHelperEngine mean that it has an interface?

Comment: Maybe i'm looking at something different, but i downloaded the code for file helpers v2 to look and its defined as `public class FileHelperEngine<T>: EngineBase` where EngineBase is abstract.

Comment: I downloaded 2.9.9 build818 "artifacts" from teamcity.codebetter.com so I was looking in the chm file, and not digging through the code itself, so you might be right.